# Prevent Windows from using the PATH env variable when resolving dll dependencies?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

When loading a DLL (either dynamically with `LoadLibrary`/`Ex` or statically) is it somehow possible to prevent Windows from using the PATH environment variable to look up the DLL/other DLLs the DLL to be loaded depends upon?

The docs I could find for the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28VS.85%29.aspx) seem to imply there is no way to prevent PATH from being searched, but maybe I'm missing something?

The reason I am asking this is that we would like to have a fail-fast scenario, when a (statically) linked DLL is missing from the application folder but is possibly present (different version) on the PATH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For dynamically loaded dlls: the easiest way to control which one is loaded is to not invoke the search logic. The search logic is only invoked if a partial path is supplied - provide a fully qualified path to the dll when calling LoadLibrary and the call will fail if the Dll doesn't exist in that location.

For statically loaded dlls: Dlls that are part of an assembly are searched for ONLY in WinSxS and the application's folder. So, create a "dummy" assembly to hold the dll. Which is as simple as creating a .manifest file with contents like this:

```
<!-- dummyassembly.manifest -->

<assembly manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity type="Win32" name="dummyassembly" version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86"/>
    <file name="thedll.dll"/>
</assembly>
```

Add this code to any project that needs to use the exact dll only:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"dummyassembly'"\
                       " processorArchitecture='*' version='1.0.0.0' type='win32'\"")
```

and it will fail to load if the dll doesn't exist in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks, great info! For 3rd party dlls which I do not control, but should be present in the app folder, will it still work with the .manifest file?

Comment: (1) You don't need to make any changes to a dll to add it to an assembly. So this will work for 3rd party dlls and your own. (2) If you have multiple DLLs, you can add them to a single assembly by repeating the <file name='abc.dll'/> node.

Comment: (3) if you are calling LoadLibrary to load a dll that depends on these 3rd party dlls and want to quickly detect when the dll fails to load: it is the dll that needs the #pragma directive, not your exe. And the 3rd party dlls will need to be in the dll folder, not the exe folder (if different).

Answer (score 2):

You could change the PATH environment variable from code before loading your dlls. And then possibly restore it afterwords.

Comment: That might actually work! My problem is that I have one DLL which I load dynamically, but would like to make sure its static dependencies are not resolved via PATH. So I possibly could scratch the PATH variable before calling LoadLibrary and restore it after LoadLibrary is done.

Comment: Remember that the PATH var is process-wide, though. If any other threads in your process may be doing something that uses it -- and that may include threads created by the OS or COM or some other component you use, not just ones you made and know about yourself -- then you may introduce mysterious, occasional failures as a result. Doing it right at the start of your process, ensuring everything is loaded before you start doing anything with it, should be fairly safe, however.